# How can I read Excel data properly in C++ (my solution is not working properly)?

Tags: c++, parsing, ifstream, getline

I have thought I have done this correctly and I have referenced other C++ code that works, but I am not getting the correct output. Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying to read an EXCEL file and parse stock info and add them to their own each object so that it gets stored like so:

```
Stock recordedStock(symbol, bidPrice, askPrice, bidSize, askSize); //Creating object Stock with attributes that were read
```

Now I created the Excel file and it is very simple. Each column is a Stock Symbol, bidPrice, askPrice, bidSize, and askSize. There are no titles to this Excel sheet. This is what it looks like:
[image]

For some reason the function which I implemented is not outputting properly. It is outputting the Amazon stock on the second row, the first row just says 35 for each problem, and no other stock info is captured. Here is my implementation:

```
void StockParser::on_market_data(const char* filename) {

    string row; // string used for row read from each line

    string symbol; //Stock object attributes that will store attributes parsed
    double bidPrice;
    double askPrice;
    int bidSize;
    int askSize;

    string temp;

    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open(filename);

    while (getline(inputFile, row)) { //loop until it reaches the end of the data

        stringstream rowStream(row); //This stream is used to read the row of data and put them in the assigned attributes

        getline(inputFile, symbol, ',');

        getline(inputFile, temp, ',');

        bidPrice = stod(temp);

        getline(inputFile, temp, ',');

        askPrice = stod(temp);

        getline(inputFile, temp, ',');

        bidSize = stoi(temp);

        getline(inputFile, temp, ',');

        askSize = stoi(temp);

        Stock recordedStock(symbol, bidPrice, askPrice, bidSize, askSize); //Creating object Stock with attributes that were read

        stockMap.insert(pair<string, Stock>(symbol, recordedStock)); /* Inserting symbol and recordedStock as a pair into the map. 
                                                                        Now you can obtain Stock attributes with the key symbol*/

    }

    inputFile.close();
```

Any help is appreciated. I am not sure what is going on here. This is me practicing how to parse files for job interviews coming up. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you reading an Excel file or a CSV (Comma Separated Values)?

Comment: Definitely looks like a CSV.

Comment: I'm curious how to read an `.xls` or `.xlsx` file without any library; which is why I'm asking.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ read csv file" or use a debugger to find issues with your program.

Comment: *.xlsx files are basically zip files. Without a library or a **lot** more code, you won't be able to just read them.

Comment: I solved my own question guys,  I had to replace the getline first parameters from inputFile to rowStream. This is a .csv file and I could not find many examples of .xls files being read. I would just convert it to .csv to be hoenst.

Comment: Side note: always check the stream state after an IO transaction and before making any decisions based on the outcome of the transaction. NEVER assume that it "Just worked."

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks !

Comment: This will fail if the file contains strings (embraced by " characters) containing commas. Also, `stod` and `stoi` may throw an exception, so one should take care of this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question. The solution was to change the first parameter to `getline` from `inputFile` to `rowStream`.